# function with the same name as a macro

Tags: c++, c, puzzle

```
#include<stdio.h>
void f(int a)
{
printf("%d", a);
}
#define f(a) {}

int main()
{
 /* call f : function */
}
```

How to call `f` (the function)? Writing `f(3)` doesn't work because it is replaced by `{}`

Comment: Not stupid. Suppose you have a macro implementing an inline replacement for `f` in its header file, and you want to use this macro to define the external implementation in the implementation file. This is a standard practice.

Comment: It is stupid as an interview question. I wouldn't like to work for a company that needs this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Does `(f)(3);` work?

The C preprocessor doesn't expand the macro `f` inside `( )`.

---

Comment: I disagree that it's silly. This is a technique any C programmer intending to use the preprocessor should know.

Comment: @Prasoon: Its arrogance to call the question "silly". Just because you know the answer, doesn't make it "silly".

Comment: because macro f needs to be in the form f(something) for C pre-processor to do replacement.

Comment: "The C preprocessor doesn't expand the macro f inside ( )." #define FOO 3   printf("%d\n",(FOO) ); works . ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
int main()
{
#undef f  // clear f!
 f(3);
}
```

Comment: @Nyan, and you downvoted for that :). Questioner hasn't mentioned such condition. Take the case if the macro is defined in one common header file and being used in several other files. For the files you don't want to use that, you will simply `#undef` it.

Comment: +1 for writing a correct answer that will probably annoy the interviewer!

Comment: This is so destructive that it indeed seems fairly obvious that the OP wants to keep the macro unless otherwise stated, not the other way around. Otherwise, in his testcase, why begin with the macro defined at all?

Answer (score 4):

Use function pointer to achieve this:

```
int main() {
    void (*p)(int a);
    p = f;
    p(3); //--> will call f(3)
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is posted by @Prasoon, another could be just introducing another name for the function, IF you can't change the function's name, neither the macro's name:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void f(int a)
{
   printf("%d", a);
}


#define fun (f) //braces is necessary 

#define f(a) {}

int main()
{
     fun(100);
}
```

Online demo : http://www.ideone.com/fbTcE

Comment: `How to call f` (aren't we calling `fun` here ? Because if calling `fun` was ok then we can change the name of the function `f()` to `fun()`. :) )

Comment: @iammilind: fun is not function, preprocessor replaces it with `f` (the actual function).